# AS3: Cannot access a property of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, null, mouse

I'm trying to trace the mouse X position with a movieclip.

**What I have done so far:**

```
public class LuckyHitBeta extends MovieClip {


    var ballReady:ballReady_mc;



private function liveIcon():void {
            ballReady=new ballReady_mc();
            addChild(ballReady);
            ballReady.y=1;
        }

 private function onEnterFrm(e:Event):void
     {          
        ballReady.x=mouseX;

    }

}
```

**Runtime error:**

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at LuckyHitBeta/onEnterFrm()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you calling the function `liveIcon()`. It seems like the `enterFrame` event happens before `ballready` is initialized.

Comment: Thank you, I had to place liveIcon(); on the Main function. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I think it means `ballReady` is `NULL`

I would do something like

```
private function onEnterFrm(e:Event):void
{          
    if (ballReady) {
        ballReady.x=mouseX;
    }
}
```